# How to use Wysiwyg upload files for my button in magento

Tags: magento, editor, wysiwyg

I want add a custom button in admin form, use files manager of Wysiwyg editor. But i can’t find anything sad about that.

Please give me any solutions if you have.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://prattski.com/2011/01/10/magento-allow-other-file-types-in-wysiwyg-editor/